# Garageband file backwards compatibility

Tags: macos, garageband

Is there anyway to open a file made with Garageband 5 in Garageband 4? Would it be possible to open it in another program, like Audacity, so that I can re-edit?

I'm a bit new to Macs, so if someone could brief me on which staple programs are not backwards compatible, that would be great!

Comment: Your description would be more aptly termed "forward-compatibility".  Backward compatibility generally means a newer program can open an older file.  You want an older program to open a newer file.

Comment: Alright...however I don't see how that comment helps in any way. My main concern in dealing with Apple software is usually backwards compatibility related. The problem is still there if I manage to open the new file, edit in Garageband 4, then try to transfer it back to Garageband 5.

Comment: "Alright...however I don't see how that comment helps in any way." That's why it's a comment, not an answer. How does it help? From now on you'll know the difference between backwards-compatible and forwards-compatible.

Comment: "The problem is still there if I manage to open the new file, edit in Garageband 4, then try to transfer it back to Garageband 5." Sorry, I really meant any sort of compatibility. Everyone has different versions of software, so I end up having to do both. Someone may change it if they want.